# Setting an array element with a sequence python

Tags: python, arrays, audio, numpy

```
import math
import pylab
from matplotlib.pylab import *
import numpy as np
import scipy.fftpack
from scipy.io.wavfile import read
w = read('c:/users/ggg.wav')
a=np.array(w[1])
l=len(a)
#from __future__ import division
#b=(l/w[0])
b=(float(l)/w[0])
c=b*1000
d=int(c/40)
print d
print l/d
e=l/d
for i in range(0,d):
    k[9]=np.array(a[(i*e)+1:((i+1)*e)])
print k
```

this is a python code to frame an audio signal. But when i executed this code,i got an error "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.". How can i avoid this error?

Comment: At which line is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine with a sample .wav

```
w = read('ggg.wav')
a = w[1]  # already an array
l=len(a)
b=(float(l)/w[0])
c=b*1000
d=int(c/40)
e=l/d
k = a[:e*d].reshape(d,e)
print k.shape
print k
print ''
k = [[] for i in range(d)]  # initialize python list
for i in range(0,d):
    k[i] = a[(i*e)+1:((i+1)*e)]
for i in k:
    print i
# or
k = np.zeros((d,e-1),dtype='int') # initialize np.array
for i in range(d):
    k[i,:] = a[(i*e)+1:((i+1)*e)]
print k
```

`w[1]` is already an np.array.  I think what you want to break `a` into blocks `e` long.  To do that, I truncated `a` and reshaped it, producing my `k`.  Your indexing misses `a[0]`, `a[e]`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is another problem with your code I can at least help you with:

You can't assign k[9] without k being undefined. E.g:

```
>>> k[9] = 'test'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'k' is not defined
```

'k' needs to be defined as an array and needs to get the 'proper' index. You can't assign the index on it straight after. 
See the following examples:

```
>>> k[9]='test'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

and

```
>>> k = [None]*10
>>> k[9]='test'
>>> k
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 'test']
```

Comment: actually sorry for the trouble. not k[9], i typed it mistakely. actually i mean k[i].

Comment: @santhu I think what he is indicating is you need to create `k`. You can do this by `k = np.empty(d)` before the `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks Ophion, I indeed meant that, but I've never worked with numpy so I had no clue it had to be done differently. :)